# Tuple + custom data type Comprehension list

Tags: haskell

I wonder if I can do comprehension list with Tuple + custom data type.

So my simple code is that

```
data T1 = Te {tea::String,tea1::String} deriving  (Show,Eq,Read)
data T2 = Te2 { teanumber::[Int], teabox::[T1]}| Other deriving (Show,Eq,Read)

tlist = [(1,{Te tea::"pepermint" tea1::"milk"}), (2,{Te tea::"blacktea" tea1::"greentea"})]


  putintothebox:: [(Int,T1)] -> T2
  putintothebox[] = Other
  putintotheboxxs = Te2 [  tnumber, Te t t1 | (tnumber, (Te t t1)) <- xs ]
```

I have got an error from

```
>>     putintotheboxxs = Te2 [  tnumber, Te t t1 | (tnumber, (Te t t1)) <- xs ]
```

WOuld you guys give me some advises ?

so basically,  I expected like this list 
T2 { teanumber= [1,2], teabox=[Te {tea::"pepermint" tea1::"milk"},Te {tea::"blacktea" tea1::"greentea"}]}

Comment: `Te2 :: [Int] -> [T1] -> T2`, so the error should be obvious. You could uncurry `Te2`, but it would still take a tuple of two lists, not a list of tuples as its argument.

Comment: `tlist` itself is riddled with errors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but it seems like you're trying to turn a list of `(Int, T1)` into a `T2` and running into a bit of difficulty?

The first thing I'm going to do here is format your code a bit to make it easier for me to read. To do this I'm just adding some whitespace in a few places - I'm not changing any functionality. I'll also add a simple `main` function, because otherwise the GHC compiler refuses to run it:

```
data T1 = Te { tea  :: String
             , tea1 :: String
             }
    deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

data T2 = Te2 { teanumber :: [Int]
              , teabox    :: [T1]
              }
        | Other
    deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

tlist = [ (1, {Te tea::"pepermint" tea1::"milk"})    -- error 1
        , (2, {Te tea::"blacktea" tea1::"greentea"})
        ]

putintothebox :: [(Int, T1)] -> T2
putintothebox [] = Other
-- errors 2 and 3
putintotheboxxs = Te2 [ tnumber, Te t t1 | (tnumber, (Te t t1)) <- xs ]

main = print (putintothebox tlist)
```

Now, just looking at this I can see a few syntax errors, which I've marked with comments:

1. This should really be `Te {tea="pepermint", tea1="milk"}`. The syntax `a :: b` operator means that you are declaring `a` to have type `b`, so it is not relevant here.
2. You seem to want `xs` to be a parameter of the `putintothebox` function; this requires a space between the two names, so `putintothebox xs` and not `putintotheboxxs`.
3. Instead of `Te2 [ tnumber, Te t t1 | (stuff) ]`, you should use the record construction syntax above and say `[ Te2 { teanumber = tnumber, teabox = (Te t t1) } | (tnumber, (Te t t1)) <- xs ]`. In fact, you can actually simplify this even more to `[ Te2 { teanumber = tn, teabox = tb } | (tn, tb) <- xs ]`.

So the final program is:

```
data T1 = Te { tea  :: String
             , tea1 :: String
             }
    deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

data T2 = Te2 { teanumber :: [Int]
              , teabox    :: [T1]
              }
        | Other
    deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

tlist = [ (1, Te {tea = "pepermint", tea1 = "milk"})
        , (2, Te {tea = "blacktea", tea1 = "greentea"})
        ]

putintothebox :: [(Int, T1)] -> T2
putintothebox [] = Other
putintothebox xs = [ Te2 { teanumber = tn, teabox = tb } | (tn, tb) <- xs ]

main = print (putintothebox tlist)
```

Except... this program isn't quite final. Because, if we try to run it, we get this nasty error:

```
Te.hs:18:20: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘T2’ with actual type ‘[T2]’
    • In the expression:
        [Te2 {teanumber = tn, teabox = tb} | (tn, tb) <- xs]
      In an equation for ‘putintothebox’:
          putintothebox xs
            = [Te2 {teanumber = tn, teabox = tb} | (tn, tb) <- xs]
   |
18 | putintothebox xs = [ Te2 { teanumber = tn, teabox = tb } | (tn, tb) <- xs ]
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Te.hs:18:40: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the ‘teanumber’ field of a record
      In the expression: Te2 {teanumber = tn, teabox = tb}
      In the expression:
        [Te2 {teanumber = tn, teabox = tb} | (tn, tb) <- xs]
   |
18 | putintothebox xs = [ Te2 { teanumber = tn, teabox = tb } | (tn, tb) <- xs ]
   |                                        ^^

Te.hs:18:53: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[T1]’ with actual type ‘T1’
    • In the ‘teabox’ field of a record
      In the expression: Te2 {teanumber = tn, teabox = tb}
      In the expression:
        [Te2 {teanumber = tn, teabox = tb} | (tn, tb) <- xs]
   |
18 | putintothebox xs = [ Te2 { teanumber = tn, teabox = tb } | (tn, tb) <- xs ]
```

The compiler is complaining about three problems:

1. The whole `putintothebox` function is returning a list of `T2`s instead of only one `T2` like it's declared to.
2. `teanumber` is supposed to be a list of integers, but we're giving it only one integer.
3. Similarly with the `teabox` field.

So basically, we want a result like this:

```
T2 { teanumber = [1,2]
   , teabox = [ Te {tea = "pepermint", tea1 = "milk"}
              , Te {tea = "blacktea", tea1 = "greentea"}
              ]
   }
```

But in the program we're actually constructing a value like this:

```
[ T2 { teanumber = 1, teabox = Te {tea = "pepermint", tea1 = "milk"}}
, T2 { teanumber = 2, teabox = Te {tea = "blacktea", tea1 = "greentea"}}
]
```

And of course, you can't make this value, because `teanumber` and `teabox` are supposed to be lists - and that's what the compiler is complaining about.

In a situation like this, the best thing to do is to start over again - in this case, we'll do this by replacing the `putintothebox xs` case with the following (everything else seems to be fine):

```
putintothebox xs = _result
```

The `_result` thing is called a *typed hole*; if we run the program with this, the compiler will show the type which should be there:

```
Te.hs:18:20: error:
    • Found hole: _result :: T2
      Or perhaps ‘_result’ is mis-spelled, or not in scope
    • In the expression: _result
      In an equation for ‘putintothebox’: putintothebox xs = _result
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [(Int, T1)] (bound at Te.hs:18:15)
        putintothebox :: [(Int, T1)] -> T2 (bound at Te.hs:17:1)
      Valid substitutions include
        Other :: T2 (defined at Te.hs:9:11)
        undefined :: forall (a :: TYPE r).
                     GHC.Stack.Types.HasCallStack =>
                     a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ at Te.hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Err’))
   |
18 | putintothebox xs = _result
   |                    ^^^^^^^
```

So at the top it's saying `_result :: T2`, i.e. we need to replace this with something of type `T2`. We can do this via either the `Other` or the `Te2` constructor; we'll replace it with `Te2` and use typed holes to help again:

```
putintothebox xs = Te2 { teanumber = _num, teabox = _box }
```

Now when we run the program including this, we get the following error:

```
Te.hs:18:38: error:
    • Found hole: _num :: [Int]
      Or perhaps ‘_num’ is mis-spelled, or not in scope
    • In the ‘teanumber’ field of a record
      In the expression: Te2 {teanumber = _num, teabox = _box}
      In an equation for ‘putintothebox’:
          putintothebox xs = Te2 {teanumber = _num, teabox = _box}
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [(Int, T1)] (bound at Te.hs:18:15)
        putintothebox :: [(Int, T1)] -> T2 (bound at Te.hs:17:1)
      Valid substitutions include
        mempty :: forall a. Monoid a => a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ at Te.hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’))
        undefined :: forall (a :: TYPE r).
                     GHC.Stack.Types.HasCallStack =>
                     a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ at Te.hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Err’))
   |
18 | putintothebox xs = Te2 { teanumber = _num, teabox = _box }
   |                                      ^^^^

Te.hs:18:53: error:
    • Found hole: _box :: [T1]
      Or perhaps ‘_box’ is mis-spelled, or not in scope
    • In the ‘teabox’ field of a record
      In the expression: Te2 {teanumber = _num, teabox = _box}
      In an equation for ‘putintothebox’:
          putintothebox xs = Te2 {teanumber = _num, teabox = _box}
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [(Int, T1)] (bound at Te.hs:18:15)
        putintothebox :: [(Int, T1)] -> T2 (bound at Te.hs:17:1)
      Valid substitutions include
        mempty :: forall a. Monoid a => a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ at Te.hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’))
        undefined :: forall (a :: TYPE r).
                     GHC.Stack.Types.HasCallStack =>
                     a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ at Te.hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Err’))
   |
18 | putintothebox xs = Te2 { teanumber = _num, teabox = _box }
   |                                                     ^^^^
```

So it's telling us we need to replace `_num` with a value of type `[Int]`, and `_box` with a value of type `[T1]`. As for how to get those values
, I'll leave this as an exercise for you; it's fairly easy to do via list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `unzip` function to pull apart the list of tuples you defined.

```
> tlist = [(1,Te {tea="pepermint", tea1 = "milk"}), (2,Te {tea ="blacktea", tea1="greentea"})]
> :t tlist
tlist :: Num a => [(a, T1)]
> :t unzip
unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
> :t unzip tlist
unzip tlist :: Num a => ([a], [T1])
> unzip tlist
([1,2],[Te {tea = "pepermint", tea1 = "milk"},Te {tea = "blacktea", tea1 = "greentea"}])
```

Once you have the tuple of lists, you can uncurry `Te2 :: [Int] -> [T1] -> T2` so that you can apply it to a tuple rather than two separate lists.

```
> :t Te2
Te2 :: [Int] -> [T1] -> T2
> :t uncurry Te2
uncurry Te2 :: ([Int], [T1]) -> T2
> uncurry Te2 $ unzip tlist
Te2 {teanumber = [1,2], teabox = [Te {tea = "pepermint", tea1 = "milk"},Te {tea = "blacktea", tea1 = "greentea"}]}
```

Putting it together, the definition of `putintothebox` could simply be

```
putintothebox:: [(Int,T1)] -> T2
putintothebox [] = Other
putintotheboxxs xs = uncurry Te2 $ unzip xs [  tnumber, Te t t1 | (tnumber, (Te t t1)) <- xs ]
```

(It's unclear if you even need `Other`, which otherwise just stands in for `Te2 [] []`.)